# Element loses sticky position on hover in MS Edge

Tags: html, css, hover, microsoft-edge, sticky

The second table header shows another element when is hovered. The problem is that when is hovered it loses the position sticky in MS Edge, and the element stuck when the table is scrolled. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

I discovered that it works if the html does not include a DOCTYPE I do not know if is relevant.

```css
td, th {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

th:hover .disp{
  display: inline;
}

.disp {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="tableId" height="360">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
          <th>Size<div class="disp">hi</div></th>
          <th>File</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>103Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>12Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>14Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>16Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>16Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>16Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Do you mean the old version of edge? The new version on chromium seems to show it correctly.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, the hover element it is showed but the element loses the stickiness.

Comment: That is indeed the old version which is shipped with win 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the issue with the MS Edge legacy browser 44.18362.449.0 and I can see the issue there.

[image]

I check the code and it looks like **position: absolute;** in **.disp** class causing this issue.

I Check the documentation but I did not get any information about this behavior.

If you set **position** as **relative** or **static** than the issue can be solved. You can use it as a workaround for this issue.

Code:

```css
td, th {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

th {
 position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

th:hover .disp{
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
}

.disp {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 8px;
  top: 8px;
}

.container {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <table id="tableId" height="360">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
          <th>Size<div class="disp">hi</div></th>
          <th>File</th>
         </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>103Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>12Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>14Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>16Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>16Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
          <td>16Mb</td>
          <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you set **display: inline-table;**. It will help to fix the issue and both elements will display in the same line.

Output:

[image]

Comment: This could be a workaround, but If I put position: relative and display:inline is not working... And I need to show the two elements in the same line, I will update the Question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please see the updated answer and let us know whether it can help you to fix the issue or nor. Thanks for your understanding.